# Why does Random.NextInt64 create duplicates and not distribute the values across the whole range

Tags: c#, random, long-integer

I have written a small C# console application to generate a million random longs

I have already included `ThreadLocal` to avoid creating duplicates

here if the code I am running:

```
var random = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
var numbers = new List<long>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(random.Value.NextInt64(1, 999999999999));
}

var metrics = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString().Length).GroupBy(x => x).Select(group => new {
    NumberLength = group.Key,
    Count = group.Count()
}).OrderBy(x => x.NumberLength);

var hashSet = new HashSet<long>();
var duplicates = new List<long>();
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    if (!hashSet.Add(item))
    {
        duplicates.Add(item);
    }
}
```

this code above is creating:

- 2 duplicates
- The numbers generated all seem to be weighted towards the higher end

[image]

Why has this out of the box C# method generated duplicate "random" numbers and also not distributed the longs across the whole range?

Comment: Because it's *random*? Random numbers can be random, including the same number twice. It's not called `Shuffle`. The number weighting: you are looking at the distribution of the *magnitude* ie the length of the number, which goes by `log10` so the results are not surprising. Try splitting it by `n / 1000000`

Comment: Thanks. Ok that makes sense. Can you expand upon the distribution part? Which bit should I try splitting by 1000000?

Comment: `numbers.GroupBy(x => x / 1000000)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicates is possible by design, [the other answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438416/1690217) provides a good start point for understanding why duplicates can occur and caclulating the probability that they might exist in a set.

> **[`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-8.0)**
> Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers.

This means that the results are *expected* to be evenly distributed across the defined range, it does not preclude the possibility of duplicate values. If a value of 2 was just returned, there should be the same probability that 2, or any other number in the range is returned.

So why do we care if there are duplicates? In a sample of 1000000 value in the range up to 999999999999 there is ~50% chance that *a* duplicate exists. If and when it happens, it does not affect the distribution, it is a property of the distribution.

> **Update:** Thankyou to [@pjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2166798/pjs) for pointing out my previous thoughts on this were wrong. The whole point and intent of `System.Random` is in fact to produce a relatively even distribution.

Using `ThreadLocal` only makes the instance accessible to this thread, which isn't about duplicates but is useful in multi-threading scenarios to ensure consistency within each thread. The problem with multiple instances of Random is that they are seeded to the system clock, and today your code will execute faster than the clock can tick which means that it is possible to declare multiple instances of `Random` that all start with the same seed, this doesn't just result in duplicate values, it results in the whole distribution being duplicated. You need to do other things in a multi-threaded context to ensure the instances of Random are not linked, or to make Random threadsafe (saef to use across multiple concurrent threads)

This code isn't using threaded or parallel processing so it's use is irrelevant in this context.

> **Update:** my initial comment on thread local was misleading.
> `ThreadLocal<T>` doesn't prevent duplicate instances of the typed value, it allows us to create isolated duplicate instances, one for each thread that needs it. It does guarantee no duplicates in the current thread though.

> Lets take duplicates out of the equation for the rest of this post :)

Your analysis of your own findings is flawed though, if you compare character length of the numbers, then there are only 9 possible value with length of 1 (another extreme case) and if we discount the possibility for duplicates to keep the math simple we are still talking a probability of 9 in 999999999999, it would surprise me to find even one value in that range. For number length of 6, we're still talking about 999999 which is only 1 millionth of the possible values. If you only sampled 1000000 values then your finding of 1 value in this range is statistically expected!

It looks like what you have actually succeeded in doing is verifying that for large value ranges the random generator is statistically consistent...

| Length | Rough Ratio | Expected | Observances |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 0.0000001 | 1 | 1 |
| 7 | 0.000001 | 10 | 10 |
| 8 | 0.00001 | 100 | 91 |
| 9 | 0.0001 | 1000 | 934 |
| 10 | 0.001 | 10000 | 9073 |
| 11 | 0.01 | 100000 | 90062 |
| 12 | 0.1 | 1000000 | 899829 |
| Total |  | 1111111 | 1000000 |

@Charliface is correct that to better observe the distribution you should split the ranges into even buckets. It makes sense that the "high" range has more results because there are more possble numbers in that range, so if you split into 10 groups of 99,999,999,999 (so divide by 99,999,999,999 not 1000000 as that would still be 999,999 groups!)

The following generates 1M values from the range 1-999999999999 and shows the distribution using both the number length and by dividing the possible values into even groups:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zOllEN

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        long maxValue = 999999999999;
        int sampleSize = 1000000;

        var random = new Random();
        var numbers = new List<long>(sampleSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(random.NextInt64(1, maxValue));
        }

        var metrics = numbers.GroupBy(x => x.ToString().Length).Select(group => {
            var minGroupValue = group.Key == 1d ? 9 : decimal.Parse(new string ('9', group.Key-1));
            var maxGroupValue = decimal.Parse(new string ('9', group.Key));
            var groupSize = maxGroupValue - minGroupValue;
            var ratio = groupSize / maxValue;
            var expected = Math.Ceiling(ratio * sampleSize);
            var count = group.Count();
            var uniques = new HashSet<long>(group).Count();
            return new {
                NumberLength = group.Key,
                GroupSize = groupSize,
                Ratio = ratio,
                Expected = expected,  
                Count = count,
                DiffPercent = Math.Round((expected - count)/expected,2),
                //Duplicates = group.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(g => g).Count()
                Duplicates = count - uniques
            };
        }).OrderBy(x => x.NumberLength);

        var numberOfGroups = 10;
        var groupSize = Math.Ceiling((decimal)maxValue / numberOfGroups);
        var ratio = groupSize / maxValue;
        var expected = Math.Ceiling(ratio * sampleSize);

        var metrics2 = numbers.GroupBy(x => x / 99999999999).Select(group => {
            var count = group.Count();
            var uniques = new HashSet<long>(group).Count();
            return new {
                Group = group.Key,
                GroupSize = groupSize,
                Ratio = ratio,
                Expected = expected,  
                Count = count,
                DiffPercent = Math.Round((expected - count)/expected,3),
                Duplicates = count - uniques
            };
        }).OrderBy(x => x.Group);

        FiddleHelper.WriteTable(metrics);
        FiddleHelper.WriteTable(metrics2);
    }
}
```

> Due to the randomness of this, each execution will produce slightly different results
> https://dotnetfiddle.net/zOllEN

| NumberLength | GroupSize | Ratio | Expected | Count | DiffPercent | Duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 900000 | 0.0000009000000000009 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 9000000 | 0.000009000000000009 | 10 | 13 | -0.3 | 0 |
| 8 | 90000000 | 0.0000900000000000900000000001 | 91 | 92 | -0.01 | 0 |
| 9 | 900000000 | 0.0009000000000009000000000009 | 901 | 839 | 0.07 | 0 |
| 10 | 9000000000 | 0.009000000000009000000000009 | 9001 | 9114 | -0.01 | 0 |
| 11 | 90000000000 | 0.09000000000009000000000009 | 90001 | 89982 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 12 | 900000000000 | 0.9000000000009000000000009 | 900001 | 899959 | 0.00 | 3 |

| Group | GroupSize | Ratio | Expected | Count | DiffPercent | Duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 100041 | 0.000 | 0 |
| 1 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 99990 | 0.000 | 2 |
| 2 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 99668 | 0.003 | 0 |
| 3 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 100289 | -0.003 | 0 |
| 4 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 100116 | -0.001 | 0 |
| 5 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 100082 | -0.001 | 0 |
| 6 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 99893 | 0.001 | 0 |
| 7 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 99704 | 0.003 | 0 |
| 8 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 99655 | 0.003 | 0 |
| 9 | 100000000000 | 0.1000000000001000000000001 | 100001 | 100562 | -0.006 | 1 |

---

If you need to prevent duplicates, for instance in card games or other lottery scenarios and the range is much smaller, then you can define the range first and sort the range based on a random number for each position and this would ensure that each value was only represented once.

```
var random = new Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(<min>, <min+max>))
                        .OrderBy(_ => random.NextDouble())
                        .Take(<sample set size>);
```

> I made that so that the code will not run, you have been warned

This absolutely chews memory, so don't do this for long ranges, for instance to pre-compute a range up to 999999999999 would chew 7.28 Terabytes! Even storing an array with 1000000 elements that have a value up to 999999999999 would at a minimum take 1000000 x 64 bits = 7.63 Mb for a single variable. For larger lists we can exclude the duplicates as we build the list:

```
var numbers = new HashSet<long>(sampleSize);

for (int i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++)
{
    while (!numbers.Add(random.Value.NextInt64(1, maxValue))) { };
}
```

See this in action in a previous fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/j04LQe

Comment: this is an amazingly detailed answer, Thank you! Really good explanation!

Comment: Just practising my reasoning ;)

Comment: I recognize and commend you for the amount of effort you’ve put into this answer, but feel compelled to point out some conceptual errors in your introductory paragraphs. Your second sentence says "Random does not specifically attempt to provide results evenly distributed across a range, only that the next value statistically does not show any calculable bias," which contains two errors.

Comment: 1) The link you provide to MS documentation states “Pseudo-random numbers are chosen with equal probability from a finite set of numbers”, which is the description of a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution). So Random does, in fact, attempt to recreate the behavior of a discrete uniform distribution.

Comment: 2) Bias in prob & stats is not a property of a distribution, it's a [characteristic of an estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator) referring to systematic deviations of the expectation of the estimated value from the true value of the parameter being estimated.

Comment: You then say "Over time, given enough cycles we might see and even distribution, or we might not, a truely random generator should show a different distribution pattern for differnt seeds." This is also incorrect. PRNGs are designed to mimic uniform distributions, the observed data should be statistically indistinguishable from uniformity *regardless of the seeding*. This is one of the major items PRNG test suites check for.

Comment: Different seed values will produce different [realizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realization_(probability)) of the simulated stochastic process, but not different distributions. Where you said "...multiple instances of Random that all start with the same seed...results in the whole distribution being duplicated," statisticians would say "...results in the whole realization being duplicated."

Comment: Your argument that not producing duplicates shows that the process is not random is also mistaken. Statisticians talk about "sampling with replacement" vs "sampling without replacement". Insisting that duplicates aren't allowed corresponds to the latter. Such samples can still be random, but the probabilities involved are conditional rather than unconditioned probabilities.

Comment: A good illustration of how this works is ["drawing straws"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475654/in-a-game-of-drawing-straws-why-are-all-turns-equally-good), where all participants have an equal likelihood of getting the short straw. Calculating the probabilities correctly for later events in the process requires accounting for (conditioning on) previous events. Not seeing duplicates in a sufficiently large sample shows that the observations are not independent rather than that they are not random. That's the core concept of a paper I co-authored on PRNG testing back in the 80's.

Comment: Here's another example of the importance and use of conditional probabilities. [Donuts!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/630620/statistics-of-lottery)

Comment: Wow thanks @pjs that's awesome feedback. To be honest the more I wrote the less convinced I was in my understanding, especially given that by changing the variables to a much smaller set, and larger, the outcome is pretty much uniform every time. That bothered me at first but if every value has equal probability then it should be an even distribution. I'll try to incorporate this feedback into an edit. But first let me read about these donuts!

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of expected even for ideally uniformly distributed random numbers due to [Birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

There is a formula on [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Arbitrary_number_of_days), for given `d` different states/days, how many random measures `n` to take to have 50% chance of a collision:
[image]

In your example for `d == 999 999 999 999`, formula gives `n(d) ~= 1 177 410`, for 50% chance of a collision. And your `1 000 000` is pretty close to this calculated `n(d)` so in this case chances for a collision is slightly below 50%, which is still quite probable.

Comment: Birthday Paradox is one of the most accessible probability vs statistics analysis we can all do. You can teach the concepts at the primary school levels and extend it in secondary education, one of my favorites +1